# What are sealer and signer nodes in PoA networks?

Tags: proof-of-authority

I have googled this and although the terms are widely used I cannot find a definition for them. Does anyone have a definition for these terms?

Answer (score 4):

not really sure about it, but in my opinion the difference is small:

In a PoA System you got Sealers and Signer - Nodes. 
Sealer are predefined in the genesis Block. So A Sealer Node is without a vote of the network allowed to mine/generate new blocks. If you want after a couple of time add new "Sealer"-Nodes, you need to add signers-Node.

A Signers Node is only allowed after n+1 (51%) Sealer-Nodes accept it. If in a Network are more signers, also the votes of the signer count.

So a Signer Node is practical the same like a sealer node, just with the different, that sealer node are defined in the genesis block and per-se allowed to mine/signing new Blocks and signers node first need a postive voting to mine new blocks.

BTW: only signers node can also be disabled to mine new block by a voting.

hope could help.

Addendum: PoA Behaviour is described in the following [github issue](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/225)